# bash: conda: command not found after installing Miniconda on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bash, path, raspberry-pi, installation, miniconda

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371773/1609514) to install Miniconda on my Raspberry Pi.  The install script ran fine but I missed the step about changing the default installation directory. Is that a big problem? I updated .bashrc with `export PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` and rebooted but I still get:

`bash: conda: command not found`

What should I do?

Debian version: 9.1
Raspberry Pi 2, ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)

Update:

So, since no-one answered I removed all the installed files at `/root/miniconda3` and re-ran the install script, this time entering the following when prompted:

`/home/pi/miniconda3`

That seems to have solved the problem (although now I have a new problem).

Now when I try to do `conda update conda` I get:

```
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ...........
Package plan for installation in environment /home/pi/miniconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    setuptools-18.1            |           py34_0         345 KB
    wheel-0.24.0               |           py34_0          77 KB
    pip-7.1.2                  |           py34_0         1.5 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         1.9 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pip:        7.1.2-py34_0  (soft-link)
    setuptools: 18.1-py34_0   (soft-link)
    wheel:      0.24.0-py34_0 (soft-link)

Error: Missing write permissions in: /home/pi/miniconda3
#
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to update packages
# into the install area '/home/pi/miniconda3'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=/home/pi/miniconda3
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with root privileges? 
ie. sudo conda update conda

Comment: It's not the best practice to just throw sudo at commands when they don't work, so it might be wise to guide him as to why sudo might be needed here (script will be installing packages).