# Unable to install anaconda 5.3.1 Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh on ubuntu18.04 64 bit machine

Tags: ubuntu, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda on 64 bit ubuntu 18.04. 
I am following below steps

1) Downloaded 64 bit installer from https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

2) Ran below code in terminal

```
cd Downloads
sudo bash Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh

           WARNING:
Your operating system appears not to be 64-bit, but you are trying to
install a 64-bit version of Anaconda3.
Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]
```

I checked my system configuration:

[System Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2704i.png)

OS-type is 64 bit and processor is ARMv8.

Could you please advise why I might be facing this error ?

Comment: Try to install `miniconda` instead of `anaconda`. It works fine for me on raspberry pi.

Comment: ARM is not x86. That is the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39371772/2449192