# How to work with miniconda in RaspBerry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, conda, miniconda

I am new to the Linux environment. I installed the miniconda in RaspBerry Pi according [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b).

Now how to open miniconda window? how to get installed list of packages?

I tried to 'conds list' command but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? It doesn't show anything? Is there an error? Did you activate the conda environment first? Please [edit] your post to show your steps.

Comment: I don’t know how to open it and work in Linux. I can not find any app icon to run it.

Comment: There is no app icon, it is purely a command-line program.