# How to change the default python version in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, raspberry-pi, python-3.8

One day ago I did a fresh installation of Raspberry Pi OS Buster and after that I installed Python3.8 in my Raspberry pi following this tutorial.
https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/

I added python alias to bashrc.

```
echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.8" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now typing `python` in terminal showing  `Python 3.8.0 (default, Jun  8 2020, 13:17:16)`

But when I run python3 it's showing Python **`Python 3.7.3`**

I added python3 alias pointing to python3.8 follwing above commands but still no luck.
Programs from Geany still showing 3.7. I changed Geany's bulid commands to python(as I set default python to 3.8)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8

import sys
print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
```

> Python version
>   3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59)

I have two questions:

1. How to run programs in Python3.8?
2. Can I uninstall python3.7?

Comment: What? The content doesn't match the title at all.

Comment: The title does not match the question at all

Comment: Sorry I was editing a half edited previous question and accidentally changed title. I have edited title now.

Comment: @Shyam3089 : First verify what your alias is really set up to (by typing `alias python3`). It should display a message saying _alias python3=/usr/local/bin/python3.8_. Then verify the version by doing a `python3 --version`.  Having said this, I must add that you have a someone unusual way to edit your `.bashrc`. Of course you can do it in that way, but there exist programs called _text editors_, and it is much easier to edit files with them, instead of using commands from the shell....

Comment: Yes it's showing alias `python3='/usr/local/bin/python3.8'`. python3 --version showing `Python 3.8.0.`  Actually I used `nano` to edit `.bashrc`

Answer (score 18):

For those of you who like working directly with the filesystem, here is what I did. Just type out the following commands one by one:

1. `sudo rm /usr/bin/python`
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`
3. `ls -l /usr/bin/python`
   *This will produce something like this:* `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jan 18 11:04 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3`

Type `python -V` or `python --version` to have it show the current version you're running.

**Alternate method** (*In my case no alternatives were found*):

`sudo update-alternatives --config python`

While you're at it, change `pip` default to `pip3`. It's a slightly different process:

1. `sudo mv /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip2 # rename`
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip`
3. `ls -l /usr/bin/pip`
   *This command will produce something like this:* `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 18 11:19 /usr/bin/pip -> /usr/bin/pip3`
   Type `pip -V` or `pip --version` to have it show the current version you're running.

**Note**: `pip2` gets confused by switchover to default `python3`, as it starts with: `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: IMHO, it should be pointed out that dealing manually with component configuration that is otherwise handled through package distribution mechanism is usually a bad idea for the sanity of the distribution tools and data. Proceed with care here.

Comment: Can you help please, are these instructions to make python 3.7 as default?

Answer (score 9):

I have not seen an "official" solution from Raspberry Pi Foundation on changing which version of Python is active.

I won't go into why you probably shouldn't use an alias to run `python`, but will answer the more important titular question.

It seems we want to add our desired version of "[alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives)" for the `python` binary.

On a fresh Raspberry Pi OS install, you just need one command:

```sh
# Adds `python3` as the alternate for `python` with priority `3`.
sudo update-alternatives --install $(which python) python $(readlink -f $(which python3)) 3
```

You can also add any number of other alternatives for `python`:

```sh
# Adds `python3.8` as the alternate for `python` with priority `3`.
sudo update-alternatives --install $(which python) python $(readlink -f $(which python3.8)) 3
```

To be nice, you should probably also add `python2`, at a lower priority:

```sh
# Adds `python2` as the alternate for `python` with priority `2`.
sudo update-alternatives --install $(which python) python $(readlink -f $(which python2)) 2
```

By default, the above will select the highest priority alternative automatically.
To manually select a system-wide version, use:

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

You can select different priorities that suit your needs.
However, I've noticed that many other "alternatives" (notably `editor`) generally use multiples of `10` for official suggested versions.
Keeping your priority values low might mean the official implementation of this (if it happens) will be compatible.
You could also pick larger numbers...

#### Notes

`dpkg -S /usr/bin/python` reports it belongs to `python-minimal`, but uninstalling that removes all `python2` from the machine (with `autoremove`). `python3-minimal` doesn't fix anything either.