# How to remove default Python, install latest version on Raspbian

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I just got my first Raspberry Pi, and I wanted to use the latest version of Python, but I don't know how to set it up so that when I run `python` in the command line, it will run Python `3.8.2`, rather than `3.7.3`. I downloaded the [latest release](https://www.python.org/downloads/) of Python from the website, but it's not a setup script, and I'm not sure how to set it to the path otherwise. Is there a way to replace the default version on Raspbian with the version I've just downloaded?

This is my first time working with any kind of Linux distro, so when I look for the answer on SO or elsewhere, I don't quite know how to word it, and there are very different answers, which makes me think I'm not asking the right question. What could I be doing wrong, and how can I set it up correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: `latest source` - you have to compile the source first. Usually all source packages have a file called "README" or similar. Or [some file with build instructions](https://github.com/python/cpython#id4). Read it.

Comment: you probably do not want to *remove* the default Python, raspian is a linux distro, so the operating system uses that Python, and you shouldn't touch it.

Comment: I would also highly suggest to not futz w/ the default python; have you considered [anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b)?

Comment: Do you get the Python3.8 when you do `python3`? Then that should be enough. It is **never** a good idea to remove/replace the system default `python`. You can instead install different versions of Python.

Comment: Also, if you are working on Raspberry Pi, you might be interested to know about [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). They have similar questions over there, like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/98600).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Way:** 
You can change Python 3.8.x as the default  to Python 3.8.x.

As you said that you have already installed the latest version.Right after that,
Add Python3.8.x & Python 3.8.x to update-alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8.0 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8.2 2
```

Update Python 3 to point to Python 3.8.x

`sudo update-alternatives --config python3` Enter 2 for Python 3.8.2 or 1 for 3.8.0

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

**Second Way:** 
Find out what python binary executables are available on your system.

```
$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python3.8.0  /usr/bin/python3.8.2
```

To Change python version:
Create an alias within user's home directory.
Open ~/.bashrc file and add new alias to change your default python executable:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.8.2'
```

Once you make the above change, re-login or source your .bashrc file:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

Check your default python version:

```
   $ python --version
    Python 3.8.2
```

Comment: I would like to add that the version that was on the os was actually `3.7.3`, rather than `3.8.0`. Also, it tells me that `--install needs <link> <name> <path> <priority>`, whereas it originally told me that the path didn't exist.

Comment: How about the second solution? try both of them and see if it is working or not! actually the first way is for ubuntu os. I thought maybe it will work. However, I am sure that the second way will fix it.