# Raspbian: Can't able to install python 3.6 using miniconda

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, conda, raspbian, miniconda

Installed miniconda on raspbian OS following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852714)

but ended up with error while installing python 3.6 as specified in the answer.

```
Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching: python 3.6*

Did you mean one of these?

    python

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda python 3.6*
```

This command returns `No packages found`

```
anaconda search -t conda python3.6
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What command did you run to try to create the environment?