# conda command not found on pi3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, miniconda

I've installed miniconda3 on my raspberry pi 3. I've added the path to the `.bashrc` which is `export PATH="/home/pi/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` at the end of the file. I did not jump many lines, I only started a new one.

But when I write conda in terminal I get the error command not found. Where could I have gone wrong? Was I suppose to add the path in a specific place in the `.bashrc` ?

Installed version from: http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh by recommendation of this answer: [How to install Anaconda on RaspBerry Pi 3 Model B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b)

Answer (score 0):

When you install Miniconda, by default it will choose "/root/miniconda3" unless you change. Follow the install process again, but when asked about the location, input this "/home/pi/miniconda3/". Copy and paste the path between quotes. After miniconda install, add this: export PATH="/home/pi/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" to .bashrc. After "sudo reboot" you will be able to use conda commands. :)